# Partially UVW Animated alpha mask for circuit board shader

Tags: animation, uv, shaders, transparency

It want a good old fashioned texture animation, not fade alpha, transparency etc.

I need to animate a circuit board growing effect.
I would take a circuit material, mask it with an alpha map and mask the alpha map with a faded texture that is animated to change UVW position from left to right (so that the animation is from right to left).

I spend a day to figure out why I can not move i.e. a wave texture or a just black image texture with faded border over the alpha mask.

How would you animate a reveal effect like that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey, i progressed a tiny bit. I think it need to combine a black and white gradient with the alpha map. That way i can generate fully transparent alpha map that has the transition to the regular alpha map.  !(https://i.ibb.co/xDrfxJ9/image.png)

Comment: Sorry for the format. I still seem to not get the formatting style to embedd images. Here is a quick video illustrating what I want to do and hopefully someone could point in in the right direction. This cost me today almost a full day so far ;(. I could use as fallback just a video of the animation. BUT that would make the full scene into a total adjustment horror. https://youtu.be/6CdpNSf0_TU   @gandalf3 hey I saw that you answered a similar question. Maybe you have an insight into this one? Its greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I wanted to have a mask that I can animate to determine the alpha channels overall opacity, overriding the alpha mask information. (can be used in literally any game vfx...) I have to figure out though how to add this as decal to other materials but that is another one.

Here is the solution: [image]

And here is the solution I used to blend it onto another material. If you can tell me how to make a more clean, proper version of this i would be very grateful. This feels a little bit wacky.

[image]

Comment: You can now animate the UV coordinates for example or use a image sequence as mask.

Comment: Here is a quick animation demonstrating the solution. The question now is rather on how to properly blend it over another base shader that it shows ONLY the growing emission material, not the dark circuits. https://youtu.be/dJcaEmKZH4o